# Can I parameterize @BeforeTest to make it open two URLs one after another?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a Selenium, Java, TestNG, Maven project. I would like to run `@BeforeTest` with two parameters as below.

```
@BeforeTest
// open first url
@Test
// run the script
@AfterTest
// close the browser

// do the same for url2
```

Comment: Annotation never mean to use with different test data, Parameter only applicable for environment setup.

Comment: You should refactor a code little and use `@dataprovider`. you can follow the [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-dataprovider/) to know how to use data provider